# Remove User with using Guid Id from API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have problem when I'm making changes about deleting user. I want to make simple it. I want to find my user on context and delete by using `UserManager`. But, I have an error:

> 'Guid'cannot impilicitly convert a 'string'.

But, I check the migrations, Id is Guid ?!

```
public class Delete
    {
        public class Command : IRequest
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
        }
        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command>
        {
            private readonly DataContext _context;
            private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
            private readonly IdentityResult _identityResult;
            public Handler(DataContext context, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IdentityResult identityResult)
            {
                _context = context;
                _userManager = userManager;
                _identityResult = identityResult;
            }

            public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(request.Id);

                var result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);

                var success = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

                if (success) return Unit.Value;

                throw new Exception("Problem saving changes");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What type of  result you return from `FindAsync`? And what type of parameter does `DeleteAsync` method accept?

Comment: Merhabalar,"Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Application.Do.Delete+Command,MediatR.Unit]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples."